# Find index of a list using the sum of the list elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that returns the index of the smallest element whose sum along all the elements to its left is bigger than a number `x`.

How can I do this in a Pythonic way?

Example:

I have a list of numbers `[32, 6, 12]` and I'm trying to make a function that would return `0` if `x < 32`, `1` if `x < 32 + 6` and `2` if `x < 32 + 6+ 12`

A non-Pythonic way would be:

```
a = [23,3,32]
i = 0
summ = 0
found = False

def example(e):
    while not found: 
        if e <= (a[i] + summ):
            found = True
            element = i
        else:
            summ += a[i]
            i += 1

    return element
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How to do this in a pythonic way

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; if you want a review of your code (*assuming it's tested and working*), try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How to do WHAT in pythonic way ?

Comment: @d-coder the question in the first paragraph/example/code I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very nice functional way to do this:

```
import itertools
import operator

xs = [32, 6, 12]
target = 5

next(i for i, x in enumerate(itertools.accumulate(xs, operator.add)) if x > target)
```

At the end of the list it raises `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def find_index(a, x):
    for i, e in enumerate(a):
        x -= e
        if x < 0:
            return i
    return i
```

Comment: Nice - but would it be better to return None at the end of the list?  Or -1?  Or raise an Exception?

Comment: @xorsyst You're right, but I don't know exactly what OP wants in such situation.

Comment: +1 for a good effort considering the opaque nature of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Found a different solution

```
>>> xs = [18,30,307]
>>> element = 40
>>> target = [sum(xs[:i+1]) for i, elem in enumerate(xs)]
>>> target.index((i for i in target if i>element).next())
1
```

With filter

```
>>> target.index(filter(lambda x: x > element, target)[0])
1
```

With filter + generator

```
>>> import itertools
>>> target.index(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x > element, target).next())
1
```